# how to add fieldname as a variable in OCCI

Tags: c++

In the below C++ code, i am updating a field of emp table based on the search value. But this code is not working properly. I am getting output as aborted.

```
void UpdateData(string field_name,string updated_value,string search_value)
{
  stmt->createStatement("UPDATE emp SET :1=:2 where search=:3");
  stmt->setString(1,field_name);
  stmt->setString(2,updated_value);
  stmt->setString(3,search_value);
  stmt->executeUpdate();
}
```

In my program user will select which field they have to update and the selected field name is passed into function as field_name parameter. updated_value is the new value entered by the user and search_value is the search key to find the appropriate record.

If i do like
      stmt->createStatement("UPDATE emp SET field_name=:2 where search=:3");

its working..

But the problem is, the field name will change according to user selection. How i can overcome this problem. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the name of the field with the `statement->setString()` method; only the values of the variables can be bound like that.
I know of only two solutions to achieve this (both aren't particularly nice):

1. Dynamically create the statement string

   ```
   string statement ="UPDATE emp SET " + fieldname + "=:1 where search=:2";
   ```
2. Prepare individual statements, each affecting one field and choose at runtime

   ```
   const string STATEMENT_FIELD_CITY = "UPDATE emp SET CITY=:1 where search=:2";
   const string STATEMENT_FIELD_LAND = "UPDATE emp SET LAND=:1 where search=:2";
   ```

Comment: The second method, while more tedious, is much more secure since the set of possible strings is likely to be known at compile time.  If you end up picking the first method, make sure you check the contents of `fieldname` before using such a statement!  Prepared statements perform escaping and other kinds of validation, but you will still be vulnerable to SQL injection since you're building the basic string from some (potentially) unknown data.

Comment: The second method also has the advantage that it is more likely to be cached by your database system since it is _fixed_, i.e. only the values of the bound variables change *not* the statement itself.